# Difference in nugets processing via `dotnet add package ..` vs nugets adding via visual studio UI

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, nuget, nuget-package, manage-nuget-packages

I need to use native `c` libraries in my library(that supports several `Core` `TF`s and `.net framework`) which is published via nuget. I configured it via `.csproj` file and `runtimes` folder. But I noticed that when I consume my NuGet via `dotnet add package ..` in some cases, the native libraries are not copied into the expected folder after consuming, however when I use the `VS` UI `Nuget package manager`->`Manage Nuget Packages for Solution`, all files are placed into correct places.
So, I assume that `Nuget package manager` makes more steps than just call `dotnet add package ..`, but it's unclear what exactly happens, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: also, if anyone can point me out on the "complex" guide to nuget configuration (preferably via `.csproj`), it will be also appreciated

Comment: Hi, any update about this issue?

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT, thanks a lot for your help, I didn't have a chance to deeply check your answer,  will do it later today

Comment: Thanks for your feedback and we will wait for your any response:)

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT, I double-checked this issue, it looks like I was wrong, at least I wasn't able to reproduce exactly the described issue. Most likely my problem was related to the difference in how consumer applications with `csproj`s in `sdk style` and `non-sdk style` are processed. Now, I see that my `non-sdk` project handles .net framework TF correctly (including via PM and Install-Package `package` way), but when I try to use .net framework in `sdk style`, the native library is not copied into the expected place. So, some more investigation is required here. Thanks a lot!

Comment: `Runtime` folder of the nuget works for new sdk style project. And it is strange why it works for non-sdk projects. You should check on [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/supporting-multiple-target-frameworks) and make sure the sructure is right. Besides, please try to use net standard library project as the nuget project. Secondly, you can use [content folder or lib folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#metadata-attributes) to copies files or reference dlls  into your main projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Actually**, `dotnet add package` does the same effect as **Nuget package manager UI** in VS IDE. They simply install a Nuget package into your project and there is no difference. No additional operations will be performed. Like add some xml node in

**So** I think there is something else wrong in your project.

Please check under tips to troubleshoot your issue:

**1)** [clean nuget caches first](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders#clearing-local-folders) or just delete all cache files under `C:\Users\xxx(current user)\.nuget\packages`.

**2)** And if the `runtimes` folder does not exist under your project, I think it is controlled by `dependency assets`. Like `ExcludeAssets=runtime or native`. It will prevent the function of `runtimes` folder. Please see [this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#controlling-dependency-assets).

So after you finishing installing the nuget package, you should check your `csproj` file, and make sure that there is no such like

```
<ExcludeAssets>runtime;native</ExcludeAssets>
```

under **PackageReference** node.

If there is any this node, please delete it.

**3)** delete `bin` and `obj` folder. Then rebuild your project to test again. Or if you use dotnet command line, you should additionally add  `dotnet build` command. In my side, I run `dotnet build -p:platform=xxx;Configuration=Release`.